# How to remove the second substring with regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
String text;
System.out.println(text);
```

In the console it looks like this:

```
The US.....................................
Illinois Commerce .......... ..............
...........................................
..........................Illinois Commerce
```

I need to get rid of the second substring `Illinois Commerce`

---

This is what I tried:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?:Illinois Commerce:.*?){2}", "");
```

I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Comment: What is your expected output? Remove complete line, or just that particular text?

Comment: Remove second encounter of `Illinois Commerce`

Comment: The `text` String should look exactly the same but without that second occurrence of `Illinois Commerce`

Comment: Are there only two `Illinois Commerce` in your input?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, this is correct. There are only 2 such substrings

Comment: @Aleksei Nikolaevich Does the second occurrence always show up at the end of the string ?

Comment: Yes, it is always there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use regex for this. What I would do is:

- Find the index of first occurrence of `"Illinois Commerce"`
- Get the substring from `index + 1` till the end.
- Replace the `"Illinois Commerce"` in that substring. That will make sure that I don't replace the 1<sup>st</sup> occurrence, because it will not be fully available in this substring.
- Then concatenate the first part of the string with the resultant substring.

This is how the code would go like:

```
int index = text.indexOf("Illinois Commerce");      
String result = text.substring(0, index + 1) + 
                text.substring(index + 1).replace("Illinois Commerce", "");     
System.out.println(result);
```

---

- `text.substring(0, index + 1)` will take the string till the `I` of the first `Illi....`.
- `text.substring(index + 1)` will start from `l` of first `Illi....` till the end of the string. So, the only string to replace is the 2nd occurrence.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
text = text.replaceFirst("(Illinois Commerce(?s).*?)Illinois Commerce", "$1");
```

Comment: `replaceAll()` for regex.

Comment: @RohitJain: `replaceFirst()` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it assuming it is following by whitespace or end of the string.

```
text = text.replaceAll("Illinois Commerce(?= ?$)", "");
```

Or the following will work for this case.

```
text = text.replaceAll("\bIllinois Commerce\s*$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only two occurrences, `lastIndexOf` may be better than a regex for this case.

Anyway, below are the regx and the `lastIndexOf` way to do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "The US.....................................\n" +
       "Illinois Commerce .......... ..............\n" +
       "...........................................\n" +
       "..........................Illinois Commerce \n";
    String toFind = "Illinois Commerce";

    System.out.print("regex\n");
    System.out.println(test.replaceAll( "(?s)^(.*)"+toFind+"(.*)$", "$1$2" )); 

    System.out.print("\nlastIndexOf\n");
    int start = test.lastIndexOf(toFind);
    System.out.println( test.substring( 0, start)
            + test.substring(start+toFind.length())); 
}
```